# How to change the height of an SSRS report based on its content?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, rendering

I have a report that has 3 pages (it's basically 3 images), one on each page.

The 3rd image should only be visible given a condition. This part works. The image is displayed or not displayed properly.

The problem is, if the image is NOT displayed, I don't want to show a blank page there. The report needs to go onto the next page.

How do I make it so that if the 3rd page isn't there, then a blank space will not be rendered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like with most formatting questions, the answer is: a **Rectangle**.

Put your image in a rectangle and use the visibility of the rectangle. When invisible, the rectangle will not consume the space.